# How to load Images to Kendo grid

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, image, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am uploading image to the network folder which is not inside the project. Uploading images works 100%. The challenge is to read those image back to the grid, i am struggling to read all the images to Kendo grid.

**Question : How can i read images from network folder to Kendo grid **

This is what i have tried,

**Reading Folder Url from the config**

```
 string Filelocation = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Home.Settings"];
```

**Model**

```
public class SettingsModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    public HttpPostedFileBase UploadImage { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

**Uploading Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [CustomAuthorize]
    public ActionResult SaveBackgroundImage(SettingsModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            string backgroundImg = "";
            string ImageName = "";
            if (model.UploadImage != null)
            {
                backgroundImg = Path.GetFileName(model.UploadImage.FileName);
                string e = Path.GetExtension(backgroundImg);
                if (model.UploadImage != null)
                {

                    ImageName = Path.Combine(Filelocation, backgroundImg);
                    model.UploadImage.SaveAs(ImageName);
                    model.ImageUrl = Url.Content(Path.Combine(Filelocation, ImageName)); // saving the Image url,wanted to try to read url

                }
            }
            return View("BackgroundImage", model);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { result = false, errormsg = "Error: " + ex.Message });
        }
    }
```

**I got this url after saving: 
  \\0.0.0.000\Main\HomeSettings\BackgroundImage\20170802_174049.jpg**

**View**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveBackgroundImage", "BackgroundSettings", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post" }, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
 {

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="txtfrom">Upload Image:</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UploadImage, new { type = "file", @id = "id_fileUploadImage", @class = "form-control input-sm", required = "required", @accept = ".jpg,.png,.gif" })
    </div>
    <br /><br />
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
        <button class="btn btn-primary " id="btnSaveFile" name="submit" type="submit">Upload Image</button>
    </div>
</div>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TTAF.Portal.Parts.Web.Models.SettingsModel>()
                            .Name("Grid")
                            .Columns(columns =>
                            {
                                columns.Bound(c => c.ImageUrl).ClientTemplate("<img src='" + Url.Content(Model.ImageUrl) + "#=ImageUrl#' alt='#=Name #' Title='#=Name #' height='62' width='62'/>");
                                //Error here: {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}
                            })
                  .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                  .Refresh(true))
                  .Scrollable()
                  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                  .Ajax()
                  .PageSize(1)
                  .ServerOperation(false) //No post back
                  .Read(read => read.Action("", ""))))

  }
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {

        var form = e.target;
        if (form.getAttribute("enctype") === "multipart/form-data") {
            if (form.dataset.ajax) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open(form.method, form.action);
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                        var obj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
                        if (obj.result == true) {
                            var ObjResults =
                            {
                                UploadImage: obj.UploadImage
                            }
                            alert(obj.UploadImage);
                            $.ajax({
                                url: '@Url.Action("SaveBackgroundImage", "BackgroundSettings")',
                                data: ObjResults,
                                type: "Post",
                                crossDomain: true,
                                async: true,
                                cache: true,

                                success: function (data) {
                                    if (data.result == true) {
                                        alert("Image Uploaded");
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        alert("Error Occured");
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else {;
                        }
                    }
                };
                xhr.send(new FormData(form));
            }
        }
    }, true);
});
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue?

Comment: I can't get the image to load on the grid. I throws an error on the grid. I have written  the comment on the column

Comment: Can you confirm that `Model` isn't null in your view context?

Comment: Yes, the model became null if i pass ImageUrl and i am not sure what is setting it to null. I have just checked my console and got this error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 10
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange